# In Gradle Exec Task, commandLine searching environment but not working directory for the executable

Tags: gradle, exec, android-gradle-plugin

It seems the Exec commandLine does not look into the workingDir for the executable command, instead searching the environment.

If your project structure is the following:

```
+ projectRoot
  + libraryMod
    - build.gradle
  + app
    - gradlew
    - build.gradle
```

and you want to run

```
./gradlew -b ../libraryMod/build.gradle someTask
```

as an exec:

```
exec{
  workingdir = getAbsolutePath("../app")
  commandLine = ['./gradlew', '-b ../libraryMod/build.gradle', 'someTask]
}
```

returns

```
[org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Starting process 'command 'gradlew''. Working directory: /Users/dev/app Command: gradlew -b /Users/dev/libraryMod/build.gradle sometask
[DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Environment for process 'command 'gradlew'': {PATH=/usr/local/bin:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin, SHELL=/bin/bash, JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home, JAVA_MAIN_CLASS_29464=org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain, TERM=xterm-256color, OLDPWD=/Users/dev/java/android/api/TestApp, USER=dev, TMPDIR=/var/folders/gj/c0vstk4s0c5632d92hp72prxy5h3g7/T/, APP_NAME_29464=Gradle, SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.HaOOxHKo1q/Listeners, DISPLAY=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.G54BIfEQjR/org.macosforge.xquartz:0, XPC_FLAGS=0x0, __CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING=0x7C580DE7:0x0:0x0, Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.pUgDDkEH6R/Render, APP_ICON_29464=/Users/dev/app/media/gradle.icns, LOGNAME=dev, LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8, XPC_SERVICE_NAME=0, PWD=/Users/dev/app, SHLVL=1, HOME=/Users/dev, BUILD_NUM=802}



[DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Changing state to: STARTING
[DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Waiting until process started: command 'gradlew'.
[DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Changing state to: FAILED
[DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle] Process 'command 'gradlew'' finished with exit value -1 (state: FAILED)
```

Is there a way to use exec such that the commandLine first argument looks in the workingDir?

I can run this successfully as a task:

```
task publishAAR(type:GradleBuild){
description 'publish the lib module aar bundle to artifactory'
buildFile = libModScript
tasks = ['someTask']
```

}

but need to incorporate into a larger build file using exec.

Answer (score 0):

Try instead setting the executable to the absolute path of the *gradlew* file.

```
exec {
    executable "${projectDir}/gradlew"
}
```

Comment: This does not work, it does start the command ./gradlew, **Starting process 'command './gradlew''. Working directory: /Users/dev/api/app Command: ./gradlew -p /Users/dev/api/libraryMod artfiactoryPublish**. But the Project Directory is still not correct **Project directory '/Users/dev/api/app/ /Users/dev/api/libraryMod' does not exist.**